# Python print redirect as stdin command line argument

Tags: python, shell

I have a binary foo which requires two command line arguments: username and password.

I have written script.py to generate the username and password. Currently, I am using print to print them to stdout and then manually copy and paste them in the shell when I call foo in shell, i.e.,

```
$python script.py
username password
(i copied and paste the output below)
$./foo username password
```

However, I need to generate special bytes which are not printable in stdout and therefore if I copy and paste from stdout, these special byte values are gone. How can I redirect my python output as the argument for foo?

BTW: I have tried using call in subprocess to directly call foo in python, this is not ideal because if I trigger a seg fault in the foo, it does not reflected in bash.

Comment: @John1024, that wont work because foo checks to see if there are two arguments. It reported error because there is not enough arguments. Thank you for the hint, but I am not worrying about password snooping. This is just an example to ask how to feed two arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run:

```
./foo $(python script.py)
```

To demonstrates that this works and provides `foo` with two arguments, let's use this script.py:

```
$ cat script.py
#!/usr/bin/python
print("name1 pass1")
```

And let's use this `foo` so that we can see what arguments were provided to it:

```
$ cat foo
#!/bin/sh
echo "1=$1 2=$2"
```

Here is the result of execution:

```
$ ./foo $(python script.py)
1=name1 2=pass1
```

As you can see, `foo` received the name as its first argument and the password as its second argument.

*Security Note:*  The OP has stated that this is not relevant for his application but, for others who may read this with other applications in mind, be aware that passing a password on a command line is not secure: full command lines are readily available to all users on a system.

Comment: You are right. I forgot I added an additional debug print in my python script. I commented it and it works now.

Answer (score 1):

So `subprocess`  worked but you didn't used because you than didn't got the output from 'foo' (the binary)?

You can use the [communicate()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) function to get output from the binary back.

Comment: "call" did not generate a segmentation fault in stdout. It does generate a core dump file, But I would like to see the seg fault info in stdout. If I just feed the arguments by directly calling foo in shell, it will have seg fault info in the shell. Can you put a proper code for using communicate? Thanks,